# How to format PDF when converting HTML to PDF in Angular

Tags: angular, pdf

I am trying to convert HTML to PDF in angular using jspdf and html2canvas. The issue is that I am not getting a straight forward way to avoid unwanted HTML elements in the PDF.

HTML code

```
<button (click)="ConvertToHtml()">Generate PDF</button>
<div id="MainSegment">
  <div id="Div1">
    test 1
  </div>
  <div id="Unwanted">
    Unwanted stuff
  </div>
  <div id="Div2">
    test 2
  </div>
</div>
```

Angular code

```
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';
import * as jspdf from 'jspdf';
import html2canvas from 'html2canvas';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  ConvertToHtml() {
    var data = document.getElementById('MainSegment');
    html2canvas(data).then(canvas => {
      var imgWidth = 208;
      var imgHeight = (canvas.height * imgWidth) / canvas.width;
      const contentDataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
      let pdf = new jspdf('p', 'mm', 'a4');
      var position = 0;
      pdf.addImage(contentDataURL, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight);
      pdf.save('sample.pdf');
    });
  }
}
```

Here, I am trying to avoid `id="Unwanted"` element.
I could probably hide(`display:none`) the element and display it again after the execution of `ConvertToHtml()` method but I wanted to know if there is a way to just fetch `#Div1` and `#Div2` element and convert only these elements to PDF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need to add to ignore the part that you do not want to format as a PDF:

```
data-html2canvas-ignore="true"
```

for example :

```
 <div id="Unwanted" data-html2canvas-ignore="true">
```